# How to create a full screen ImageBackground in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app with a single Signin component. I just need to add a full screen ImageBackground component. **The problem is, the image only get the hight and width as pixels. It doesn't response for 100%.** I tried with width : 'auto' and width : null but those are also not working. How can I get the image in full screen size?

Signin.js

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bgStyles: {
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    flex: 1
  },
});

const Signin = () => {
  return (
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.bgStyles}
        source={require('../../../public/static/images/w.jpg')}
        resizeMode='contain'
      >
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
  );
};
```

Result before adding resizeMode = 'contain':

[image]

Result after adding resizeMode = 'contain':

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  flex:1 in your view :

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.bgStyles}
        source={require('../../../public/static/images/w.jpg')}
      >
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
        <Text>TEXT</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: can you check this link, its working in my case :https://snack.expo.io/ByKDDJxz8

Comment: Any idea why it is not working in my emulator? Maybe should I recreate the emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `ImageBackground` as a parent component. No need to add `View` before the `ImageBackground`:

```js
<ImageBackground
  style={[{flex: 1}, styles.bgStyles]} // flex: 1 make it full screen and additionally you can add your another style
  source={require('../../../public/static/images/w.jpg')}
>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>TEXT</Text>
      <Text>TEXT</Text>
      <Text>TEXT</Text>
  </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Have you added props `resizeMode="contain"` to `ImageBackground` ?

Comment: Yes I added it, please check the question again, I updated it with the result image after adding resizeMode. Still not working

Comment: What if you `resizeMode="stretch"` ?

Comment: Then it takes full width, but not full height. Height is the same as previous

Comment: Heyy @DavidJohns I updated the answer. Add `View` inside the `ImageBackground` with `flex: 1` style.

Answer (score 0):

```
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
```

Please try this style